# Eigenspaces of semisimple element in finite unitary group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, classical-groups

Let $G=GU(V)=GU_{n}(q)$ - the general unitary group acting on a vector space $V$, over the finite field of $q^2$ elements.

Let $1 \neq s\in G$ be semisimple and $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ an eigenvalue of $s$.

I'm looking for a proof of the following claim:

CLAIM:  $E_{\lambda}$ - the eigenspace of $\lambda$,   is either totally isotropic or non-degenerate with respect to the unitary (hermitian) form.

Thanks.